# combining rows of data R

Tags: r

I have a data frame where I want to combine data frame rows.  My data frame looks like this.

```
col id, col1, col2, col3, col4

1, 1, , , 5             
1, , 1, , 5             
1, , , 1, 5
```

I would like the final result to look like

```
col id, col1, col2, col3, col4
1,1,1,1,5
```

Any ideas?  I have tried aggregate, cant get it to work properly.

edit:

```
data<- data.frame(colID=c(1,1,1,2,2), col1=c(1,NA,NA,NA,2), col2=c(NA,1,NA,2,NA), col3=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA), col4=c(5,5,5,7,7))

finaldata=data.frame(colID=c(1,2), col1=c(1,2), col2=c(1,2), col3=c(1, NA), col4=c(5,7))
```

should build the data frame and the final data frame

Comment: are the gaps filled with NAs?

Comment: The question made no sense so I looked at the original in the editing panel and applied the needed formatting. That is probably _not_ a real R object yet, since it has spaces in the column names, so the OP still needs to supply a proper example. And there needs to be better problem specification. Will there ever be multiple values in col4 within column_id categories? What is the aggregation function that should be applied to columns 1-3?

Comment: sorry, the formatting is not right for what the object looks like. It is a dataframe. I am going to try and fix the question. No, col 4 will always be the same. Bascially, column id is unique, col1-3 have a numeric value. I want to combine all 3 rows

Comment: no.  Gaps are blanks...could be NAs if needed

Comment: @user1652961: Please do `dput(mydataframe)` (with whatever your data frame is called) and post the result- that will let us reproduce it.

Comment: editted the initial question to include code that can build the data frame and final data frame

Comment: Do you want to use a function like `mean` or `median` for combination?

Comment: think I figured it out.  Use sum, change the blanks/Nas to 0's....

Answer (score 4):

You can do this any number of ways.  But first you need to clarify a few things to yourself.

- is there always only one number given group?  i.e. will you ever have data like this?

`data.frame(colID=c(1,1,1,2,2), col1=c(1,1,NA,NA,2), col2=c(NA,1,NA,2,NA), col3=c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA), col4=c(5,5,5,7,7))`

If so what do you do with the duplication? `sum`? `mean`?

- do the groups in `col4` always coincide with the groups in `colID` as in your example? or is `col4` just another data column?

---

the package `plyr` gives a pleasant syntax for doing this kind of thing.  I'll use `median` for an aggregation function.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, 
      .(colID), 
      summarise, 
      col1=median(col1, na.rm=TRUE),
      col2=median(col2, na.rm=TRUE),
      col3=median(col3, na.rm=TRUE),
      col4=median(col4, na.rm=TRUE))
```

However there are many other possibilities.  the `data.table` package is excellent, especially for large data sets.  You can also do this using the base R function `aggregate`.

## data.table

A `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data)
DT[ , lapply(.SD, median, na.rm = T), by= colID, .SDcols = paste0('col',1:4)]
```